# Three.js shader error on different computers (same browser)

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

I've been developing with **Three.js** over the past 3 months and have been using it on several browsers and computers just fine. Last week on my home computer, I get this error whenever I try and load my website:

```
three.js:29948 THREE.WebGLProgram: shader error:  0 gl.VALIDATE_STATUS false gl.getProgramInfoLog C:\fakepath(254,9-30): error X3004: undeclared identifier 'IncidentLight'

Warning: D3D shader compilation failed with default flags. (vs_3_0)
 Retrying with avoid flow control
C:\fakepath(254,9-30): error X3004: undeclared identifier 'webgl_45daf4aa877f103d'

Warning: D3D shader compilation failed with avoid flow control flags. (vs_3_0)
 Retrying with prefer flow control
C:\fakepath(254,9-30): error X3004: undeclared identifier 'webgl_45daf4aa877f103d'

Warning: D3D shader compilation failed with prefer flow control flags. (vs_3_0)
Failed to create D3D shaders.
```

The website is live and doesn't work on strictly a handful of computers but works on the computers at work. I've made sure to check if **WebGL** was enabled on the browsers where the site *isn't* working but it's enabled.

Comment: What makes you think it depends on a browser type?

Comment: @enkryptor That's typically the common reason when I research issues on Three.js working with some browsers and not others, so that's what I think this.

Comment: Does your shader require some webgl extensions? If I have to guess, some computer don't have the webgl extensions either your or three.js needs. Also, which version of Three.js do you have?

Comment: But is it your guess for now, or did you really tried to run it on your home computer with different browsers? What browsers do work, then?

Comment: I'm sorry if it sounded offensive, but you said "doesn't work on strictly a handful of computers but works on the computers at work", and it was about different computers, not different browsers. I was asking about different browsers on a same computer. Which of them do work and which do not?

Comment: @SterlingW Revision 74. As for requiring webgl extensions, nothing out of the ordinary from what I understand. I've gotten this to work on several different computers where I simply hopped on that PC for the first time, went to the website, and it worked without any configurations.

Comment: @enkryptor My miscommunication, I'm sorry. It's more specific computer related than related to any one browser. I can get it to work on a few machines at work (PC and Mac) but then when I get home or use a few different family PC's (I traveled last weekend) it won't work on their machines, even with the same browsers on the same version as the PC's that it _did_ work on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That could be the known issue with certain hardware, appeared in a new Three.js version - https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/8161

The issue is fixed in the dev branch. There is a workaround though:

> Compilation fails on functions `IncidentLight getPointDirectLight` and `IncidentLight getDirectionalDirectLight`. Modify those functions to void types:

```
void getDirectionalDirectLight( out IncidentLight directLight, const in DirectionalLight directionalLight, const in GeometricContext geometry );

void getPointDirectLight( out IncidentLight directLight, const in PointLight pointLight, const in GeometricContext geometry );
```

Comment: A little more summary details may be nice, just in case that link went away.